# Preventing spurious -m32 flag when running running setup.py build_ext

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling, distutils

I'm trying to cross-compile `numpy` for arm (BeagleBone & RPi). I am running on debian buster, with a 32bit cross-compilation toolchain, including i386 (32bit) libraries and all necessary arm toolchains.

When I run:

```
 export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib; \ 
 python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the following error:

```
C compiler: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -m32 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/ -m32 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/ -fPIC
compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: _configtest.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’; did you mean ‘-mbe32’?
```

I've traced through `numpy`'s setup.py file and found that ultimately these settings seem to be generated in the `distutils.core._setup_distribution.get_command_obj("build")` call.

The error is quite self explanatory, and trying to run the command without the -m32 flags seems to work correctly.

Edit: further digging has revealed that these parameters come to the build script via:

```
sysconfig.get_config_var("LDSHARED")
```

I'm still stumped because the following still doesn't work:

```
$LDSHARED="gcc -pthread -shared" python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LDSHARED'))"

gcc -pthread -shared -m32 -m32
```

Comment: I don't think distutils/setuptools support cross-compilation. Build natively in virtual machines or Docker containers.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could run an arm VM on an intel box. The whole point is to avoid the excruciatingly long build times.

At the same time, more hours of going down this rabbit hole, I'm on the verge of giving up, but have found this script that purports to achieve the goal: https://gist.github.com/benfogle/85e9d35e507a8b2d8d9dc2175a703c22

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this LDSHARED parameter is coming from the Makefile that was used during the build of the python host itself. Under most scenarios it makes sense to have it this way, but a combination of cross-compiling and the arm gcc not accepting that flag made it problematic...

This may very well be unresolvable and I have instead resorted to capturing the parameter from the gcc itself via a symlink/bash script.